# Obtain the Linux UID of an Android App

Tags: android, linux, uid

I would like to be able to get the Linux UID (user ID) of an installed Android application.

Excerpt from [Security and Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html): "At install time, Android gives each package a distinct Linux user ID. The identity remains constant for the duration of the package's life on that device."

Is there a way to retrieve this UID?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `PackageManager` and `getApplicationInfo()`.

Comment: Yes, I missed the last field in the ApplicationInfo class. Thank you :)

Comment: do you know how we can get the uid of the App from the linux kernel of android?

Comment: @user489152 If the app currently has an open process, then the `ps` command which walks the /proc/pid structure exported by the kernel will show the UID of that process.

Answer (score 56):

`adb shell dumpsys package com.example.myapp | grep userId=`

Comment: Only works when app is running?

Answer (score 12):

- The ‍`packages.xml` file present in `/data/system`
- The `packages.list` file present in `/data/system`

Contain the list of applications installed and their corresponding UID's.

Answer (score 9):

Use `android.os.Process.myUid()` to get the calling apps UID directly.

Using the PackageManager is not necessary to find the own UID.

Answer (score 4):

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
try {
    applicationId = String.valueOf(packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.example.app", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As CommonsWare already wrote, you can use `PackageManager` to get the UID.

Here's an example:

```
int uid;
try {
    ApplicationInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
            context.getPackageName(), 0);
    uid = info.uid;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    uid = -1;
}
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "UID = " + uid);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way on the commandline / in shell scripts is

```
stat -c '%U' /data/user/0/id.of.app
```