# How to open "adb shell" in context of application being debugged (on non-rooted device)?

Tags: android, adb, uid

When I just run `adb shell`, I get shell running from `uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell)`, without ptrace access to my application.

How to open a shell with the same UID as launched application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654718/adb-shell-when-multiple-devices

Comment: @tim, Wrong duplicate candidate. The linked question is about choosing device for shell to be opened in. This questions is opening shell with specific uid.

Comment: That is not a duplicate of this question. That asks for specifying a particular device, this asks for a specific UID

Comment: Try an emulator where adb runs as root; if you need to use a real device where run-as is broken, you can temporarily merge an SSH or cruder shell server configured to run as a distinct process into a build of your app, and use that.

Comment: I'm trying shell server approach with my ["dive"](http://vi-server.org/pub/dived_armel), but AF_UNIX sockets between applications seem to be restriced by SELinux on this device. It's probably a time for `socat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround way using socat:

1. Add `android.permission.INTERNET` to your application;
2. Put [socat binary](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51837955&postcount=28) ([mirror](http://vi-server.org/vi/pub/socat_android)) to `/data/local/tmp/`. Ensure everybody can start it;
3. Add `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/local/tmp/socat tcp-l:4446,fork,reuseaddr exec:/system/bin/sh,pty,stderr,setsid");` at startup of your Java-based application;
4. `adb forward tcp:4446 tcp:4446`
5. Use `` socat `tty`,raw,echo=0,opost=1 tcp:127.0.0.1:4446 `` on host to connect to the shell in your application context.

Note that this setup is not secure and should not be left in production app.

Answer (score 6):

Use `run-as <your package name>` to switch to your app's UID or `run-as <your package name> <command>` to run a single command with your app's UID.

Comment: It says `run-as: Package 'com.example.myapp' is unknown` for all packages... Maybe it's ["run-as doesn't work after update to 4.3"](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373)?

Comment: Do you have a debug build of the app?  Are you absolutely sure the package name is exactly correct?  There are devices where this doesn't work, but don't give up too soon.

Comment: It is installed from MainActivity-debug.apk, so I expect it to be debug. The package name is obtained from `AndroidManifest.xml` and `dumpsys package com.example.myapp` works. The device is `Samsung GT-N7100` running Android 4.3.

Answer (score 5):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881017/1590950):

- The packages.xml file present in /data/system
- The packages.list file present in /data/system

Contain the list of applications installed and their corresponding UID's.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927898/1590950) in the same question suggests:

```
adb shell dumpsys package com.example.myapp | grep userId=
```

You can then open your shell as normal and run:

```
$ su <UID>
```

You should then have the same access and privileges as the app that uses that UID.

Comment: `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`. Of course it is not a problem on rooted devices.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this on an unrooted device unfortunately due the the built in security restrictions. I'd be happy to be proved wrong though.

Comment: You can debug the application, so you can start the shell indirectly. The question is about how to do it conveniently.

Comment: Ultimately this is not a very useful answer, as *if* you have the ability to `su` then *you are already root* (or able to become so) and therefore can `ptrace` the process *without* needing to match its UID.